How to setup a folder in C drive to contain android project for newer android studio
I encountered below issues when copy and paste android project into a new folder.
The android project file is from older android studio  version (ie. 3.6 something)
When I open it with Android studio girafe, issues as below.

Project view has no android in android studio
No build options
In File Project Structure. No SDK location , no gradle version in project

Below is what I did:

I had an existing android project in a folder name: MyAndroidApp which include everything as below

.gradle
.idea
app
gradle
build,gradle.properties, gradlew , local.properties, settings, myAppName.iml

I created a new folder in c-drive ,say , name: FolderGirafe

I copied MyAndroidApp into FolderGirafe

I opened this MyAndroidApp with Android Studio Girafe.

Issues as above. I cannot build and run.


Please advise what are the proper steps I need to do.
Thanks

Delete .gradle and  .idea folder and the .iml file. That should be sufficient. Deleting Gradle is a bad idea as the ´gradle´/gradlew build script depends on a certain gradle version and if Android Studio does not know them it may use the latest version which is most likely incompatible. The .properties files should be checked manually. I would not delete them.

I will get back here after using your approach to this problem. I really appreciate your help.

What is IML file ? Deleted all the files you mentioned.
will this affects the project when move to higher version of android studio?
now Can deploy to Android Phone,but have this issue: Signature is different.
I need to delete the installed app and rebuilt and re-deployed. It is OK.
Will this signature affect my same app in google play store if I submit it? Thanks. Sorry took me a while to reply.

The signature depends on the used signature key and thus where you have created the keystore with the key in it. If you have overwritten the keystore or use a different keystore you get a different signature. If it affects Google Play Store depends if you publish signed APK files or upload an appbundle signed with an upload key.

Thank you so much. I raise the signature thing on other thread. As far as I concerned your solution solved my problem. Thanks
